# OpenIddict Refresh Token Flow issue ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict

I am trying to set my refresh token life time to 2 weeks. I have tried via .. FromSeconds, FromMinutes, FromHours, but it always sets the refresh token to the same lifetime as the access token. I would appreciate any help. This is what I currently have in my configureServices:

```
services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
{
    // Register the Entity Framework stores.
    options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<AppDbContext>();

    // Register the ASP.NET Core MVC binder used by OpenIddict.
    // Note: if you don't call this method, you won't be able to
    // bind OpenIdConnectRequest or OpenIdConnectResponse parameters.
    options.AddMvcBinders();

    // Enable the token endpoint.
    options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");

    // Enable the password flow.
    options.AllowPasswordFlow()
            .AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
            .SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
            .SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20160));

    // During development, you can disable the HTTPS requirement.
    options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
});
```

Comment: `but it always sets the refresh token to the same lifetime as the access token` -> how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: This is the body of the 400 I get: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The refresh token is no longer valid."}. It is set to 14 days out but as soon as the access token is no longer valid so is the refresh token regardless of how far out I set it.

Comment: It's worth noting that the refresh tokens are single-use tokens (unless you disable sliding expiration). Are you sure it's not what's causing the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Please note: the following post won't resolve the issue:
http://kosmisch.net/Blog/DotNetEssential/Archive/2017/9/11/openiddict-refresh-token-flow-issue-aspnet-core-20.html

Latest summary about the issue:
When login with user name and password, the following data is inserted into openiddicttoken table:

```
Id  ApplicationId   AuthorizationId Ciphertext  End Hash    Start   Status  Subject Type
```

1   NULL    NULL    NULL    2017-10-12 11:24:26.0000000 +00:00  NULL    2017-09-12 11:24:26.0000000 +00:00  valid   1   refresh_token

Then a refresh_token grant type request was done. 
The above record is updated with only change is the Status column, which has changed from **valid** to **redeemed**

```
Id  ApplicationId   AuthorizationId Ciphertext  End Hash    Start   Status  Subject Type
```

1   NULL    NULL    NULL    2017-10-12 11:24:26.0000000 +00:00  NULL    2017-09-12 11:24:26.0000000 +00:00  redeemed    1   refresh_token

And the response JSON doesn't include the new refresh token attribute.

I think for the second refresh, I thought at least one of the Start or End column should change since I configured to use sliding expiration.

But it is not the case. So I think there might be one issue with this refresh token method. Could you please have a look?

In the example: https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/RefreshFlow

I downloaded and I can see each time when a refresh is done, a new token will be inserted, which is very different from the behaviour I had. BTW, I have changed the sample code to use slide expiration as well.

The main difference is my model is using int as TKey while the sample is using GUID. So I am wondering whether this is something to do with that?

```
options.UseOpenIddict<int>();
```

Found out the root cause for my issue:

```
 // Create a new authentication ticket holding the user identity.
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, *new AuthenticationProperties(),* OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

While it should be:

```
// Create a new authentication ticket holding the user identity.
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, properties, OpenIdConnectServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Comment: I highly doubt setting `SaveToken` to `true` "fixes" your issue as its only effect is to persist the access token as an authentication property so you can easily access it from your own code. If you take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Extensions/blob/dev/src/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Validation/OAuthValidationOptions.cs#L45), you'll see it's enabled by default, so forcing the `true` value cannot have any effect.

Comment: If you see the `The refresh token is no longer valid` error returned from your own code, that likely means Identity was unable to retrieve the user profile corresponding to the user ID stored in the refresh token, which happens when you remove the user from the database. Could that explain your issue?

Comment: Yes, you are right about that attribute. The user is always in the database and I never removed it. And after I added that code it is always working now. However while I was updating the code, the OpenIdDict packages were just updated to 2.0 release candidate version. I think there might be an bug in the code before the update. So we probably explorer a little bit more.

Comment: @michael could you please try to refresh your OpenIdDict packages and see whether the issue still happens? There were some updates last night.

Comment: No bug was fixed in RC1. Are you sure you've correctly configured Data Protection (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/)? Other sources of issues might include a problem with your database, where refresh tokens metadata are stored.

Comment: @Pinpoint Please refer to the answer I provided and the new issue I found.

Comment: `which is very different from the behaviour I had` > this behavior hasn't really changed since the first OpenIddict beta: refresh tokens have always been treated as single-use tokens (unless you set `UseSlidingExpiration = false`, in this case no refresh token is returned on subsequent token requests so that the app must continue to use the previously issued token).

Comment: That said, I'm considering changing how that works in the next version to allow returning a single refresh token and updating its expiration date dynamically in the DB, pretty much like what you describe.